# ¿Como puedo llenar un arraylist desde mi clase main?

Tags: java, poo, arraylist

Mi caso es que necesito llenar un `arraylist` desde la clase main, pero el arraylist está en la clase **`inventario`** ya que el ejercicio me pide que debe haber métodos en esa clase.

En si lo que necesito es ir llenando el arraylist y hacer las consultas que están en el menú.

***Código:***

```
package carniceria;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class main {

    //Campos definidos static son variables globales.
    static Scanner leer;
    //static ArrayList<carniceria> listaInventario;
    static inventario objeto;
    //Colores que se usaran 
    static String black = "\033[30m";
    static String red = "\033[31m";
    static String green = "\033[32m";
    static String yellow = "\033[33m";
    static String blue = "\033[34m";
    static String purple = "\033[35m";
    static String cyan = "\033[36m";
    static String white = "\033[37m";
    static String reset = "\u001B[0m";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        //Instanciamos el objeto llamado leer y listaParticipante 
        leer = new Scanner(System.in);
        //listaInventario = new ArrayList();
        //OBJETO AUXILIAR

        int Op;
        String REPETIR;
        do {
            String NOMBRE;
            double PRECIO;
            REPETIR = "S";
            //AL RETORANAR MENU UN (INT) LA VARIABLE Op seria igual a lo que 
            se ejecutara en el Switch
            Op = Menu();
            switch (Op) {
                case 1://1. REGISTRO DE Carnes
                        leer.nextLine();
                        System.out.println("INGRESE EL NOMBRE DEL PRODUCTO:");
                        NOMBRE= leer.nextLine();
                        System.out.println("INGRESE EL PRECIO DEL PRODUCTO:");
                        PRECIO= leer.nextDouble();
                        objeto = new inventario();
                        objeto.registrarProducto();

                    break;
                case 2:

                        objeto.buscarProductoPorNombre();


                    break;
                case 3:

                        objeto.buscarProductoPorPrecio();
                        break;
                case 4:

                        objeto.eliminarProducto();

                    break;
                case 5:
                    System.out.println("**************************************************");
                    System.out.println((char) 27 + "[34;42mGRACIAS POR USAR ESTE PROGRAMA");
                    System.out.println("****************************************************");
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println((char) 27 + "[31;43mOPCION INCORRECTA\n");
            }
        } while (Op != 5);

    }

    public static int Menu() {
        System.out.println("\n\n");
        System.out.println("<><><><><><><><><><><><><><><>");
        System.out.println(green + "<<<<**MENU DE OPCIONES**>>>>");
        System.out.println("<><><><><><><><><><><><><><><>");
        System.out.println("------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("1. REGISTRO DE PRODUCTO");
        System.out.println("2. BUSQUEDA DE PRODUCTO POR NOMBRE");
        System.out.println("3. BUSQUEDA DE PRODUCTO POR PRECIO");
        System.out.println("4. ELIMINAR PRODUCTO");
        System.out.println("5. FIN");
        System.out.println("------------------------------------------");
        System.out.print(red + "ELIJA SU OPCION: ");
        //SE RETORNARA UN ENTERO 
        return leer.nextInt();
    }

}
```

***Clase inventario:***

```
package carniceria;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class inventario extends carniceria {
static String ruta = "C:\\Users\\Frank\\Desktop\\carniceria.txt";//en donde se creara el archivo
static ArrayList<carniceria> listaInventario = null;
static inventario oInventario;
static Scanner leer = null;
    public inventario() {
        super();

    }

    public void registrarProducto() {
        //VARIABLES LOCALE
        //oInventario = new inventario();
        System.out.println("HOLA");
        oInventario.setNombre("");
        oInventario.setPrecio(0);
        listaInventario.add(oInventario);
    }

    public void buscarProductoPorNombre() {
        //VARIABLES LOCALES Pos y DNI

        String NOMBRE = "";
        System.out.println("\n\n");
        System.out.println("<><><><><><><><><><><><><><><>");
        System.out.println("<<<<**BUSCAR PRODUCTO POR NOMBRE**>>>>");
        System.out.println("<><><><><><><><><><><><><><><>");
        System.out.print("NOMBRE DEL PRODUCTO QUE DESEA BUSCAR:");
        NOMBRE = leer.next();
        //BUSCAM
        for (int i = 0; i < listaInventario.size(); i++) {
            oInventario = (inventario) listaInventario.get(i);
            if (oInventario.getNombre().equals(NOMBRE)) {
                System.out.println("======================================");
                System.out.println("::INFORMACION DEL PRODUCTO::");
                System.out.println("======================================");
                System.out.println("NOMBRE DEL PRODUCTO: " + 
                oInventario.getNombre());
                System.out.println("PRECIO DEL PRODUCTO: " + 
                oInventario.getPrecio());
            } else {
                System.out.println("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
                System.out.println("EL PRODUCTO NO EXISTE");
                System.out.println("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");

            }
        }
    }

    public void buscarProductoPorPrecio() {

        //VARIABLES LOCALES Pos y DNI

        double PRECIO;

        System.out.println("\n\n");
        System.out.println("<><><><><><><><><><><><><><><>");
        System.out.println("<<<<**BUSCAR PRODUCTO POR PRECIO**>>>>");
        System.out.println("<><><><><><><><><><><><><><><>");
        System.out.print("PRECIO DEL PRODUCTO QUE DESEA BUSCAR:");
        PRECIO = leer.nextDouble();
        //BUSCAMOS EL 
        for (int i = 0; i < listaInventario.size(); i++) {
            oInventario = (inventario) listaInventario.get(i);
            if (oInventario.getPrecio() == PRECIO) {
                System.out.println("======================================");
                System.out.println("::INFORMACION DEL PRODUCTO::");
                System.out.println("======================================");
                System.out.println("NOMBRE DEL PRODUCTO: " + 
                oInventario.getNombre());
                System.out.println("PRECIO DEL PRODUCTO: " + 
                oInventario.getPrecio());
            } else {
                System.out.println("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
                System.out.println("EL PRODUCTO NO EXISTE");
                System.out.println("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");

            }
        }
    }

    public void eliminarProducto() {
        //VARIABLES LOCALES 
        int Pos;

        String NOMBRE = "";
        System.out.println("\n\n");
        System.out.println("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
        System.out.println("<<<**ELIMINACION DE  PARTICIPANTE**>>>");
        System.out.println("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
        System.out.println("NOMBRE DEL PRODUCTO:");
        NOMBRE = leer.next();

        for (int i = 0; i < listaInventario.size(); i++) {
            oInventario = (inventario) listaInventario.get(i);
            if (oInventario.getNombre().equals(NOMBRE)) {
                System.out.println("^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^");
                System.out.println("::INFORMACION DEL PARTICIPANTE::");
                System.out.println("^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^");
                System.out.println("NOMBRE DEL PRODUCTO: " + oInventario.getNombre());
                System.out.println("PRECIO DEL PRODUCTO: " + oInventario.getPrecio());
                System.out.println("ESTA SEGURO DE ELIMINAR AL PARTICIPANTE(S/N)?:");
                if (leer.next().equalsIgnoreCase("S")) {
                    listaInventario.remove(oInventario.get(i));
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x");
                System.out.println("EL PRODUCTO NO EXISTE");
                System.out.println("x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x");
            }
        }

    }

    public void crearArchivo(String nombre, double precio) {

        //creacion del documento
        String espacio = " "
                + " "
                + " "
                + " ";
        try {
            //Crear un objeto File se encarga de crear o abrir acceso a un archivo que se especifica en su constructor
            File archivo = new File(ruta);

            //Crear objeto FileWriter que sera el que nos ayude a escribir sobre archivo
            FileWriter escribir = new FileWriter(archivo, true);

            //Escribimos en el archivo con el metodo write 
            escribir.write( "NOMBRE DEL PRODUCTO:" + nombre + espacio + espacio + "Precio del Produto" + precio );

            //Cerramos la conexion
            escribir.close();
        } //Si existe un problema al escribir cae aqui
        catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error al escribir" + e);
        }

    }

    public void leerArchivo(String ruta) {

        //leer archivo
        //Leer lo que esta dentro del texto
        //Creamos un String que va a contener todo el texto del archivo
        String texto = "";
        try {
            //Creamos un archivo FileReader que obtiene lo que tenga el archivo
            FileReader lector = new FileReader(ruta);

            //El contenido de lector se guarda en un BufferedReader
            BufferedReader contenido = new BufferedReader(lector);

            //Con el siguiente ciclo extraemos todo el contenido del objeto "contenido" y lo mostramos
            while ((texto = contenido.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(texto);
            }
        } //Si se causa un error al leer cae aqui
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error al leer" + e);
        }
    }

    public int buscar(String NOMBRE) {
        //RETORNARA UN ENTERO 
        //VARIABLE LOCAL pos
        int pos = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < listaInventario.size(); i++) {
            oInventario = new inventario();
            oInventario = (inventario) listaInventario.get(i);
            if (oInventario.getNombre().equals(NOMBRE)) {
                pos = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        return pos;
    }
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y de paso ganes tu primera medalla, también es muy importante que leas [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad.

Answer (score 0):

Te pongo una respuesta por que el comentario se me queda corto. Vamos por pasos:

1. Indica que lista es la que quieres que se le pueda insertar, deduzco que es `listaInventario`
2. Ya tienes un método en tu clase `inventario` que hace lo que tu pides(`registrarProducto`), solo necesitas pasarle por parámetros los campo nombre y precio.
3. Te veo un comportamiento no deseado aquí en este fragmento:

   ```
   do {
       String NOMBRE;
       double PRECIO;
       REPETIR = "S";
       //AL RETORANAR MENU UN (INT) LA VARIABLE Op seria igual a lo que 
       se ejecutara en el Switch
       Op = Menu();
       switch (Op) {
           case 1://1. REGISTRO DE Carnes
                   leer.nextLine();
                   System.out.println("INGRESE EL NOMBRE DEL PRODUCTO:");
                   NOMBRE= leer.nextLine();
                   System.out.println("INGRESE EL PRECIO DEL PRODUCTO:");
                   PRECIO= leer.nextDouble();
                   objeto = new inventario();
                   objeto.registrarProducto();

               break;
   ```

Cada vez que quieres registrar un producto nuevo, estas sobrescribiendo `objeto` y perderás todos los productos insertados anteriormente. Deberás de extraer 'objeto = new inventario();' fuera del while para evitar este comportamiento.

4. La estructura de datos de tu programa es muy rara. No le veo sentido que inventario extienda de carnicería. En todo caso deberían de tener cada uno un objeto del otro (una carnicería tiene un inventario, y un inventario esta relacionado a una carnicería)
5. Tampoco tiene sentido que dentro de `inventario` tengas un objeto de tipo `inventario` para meterle a ese objeto los valores de nombre y valor. Para eso, no crees el objeto y añádeselos a la propia clase, no al objeto nuevo.